# Running a bitcoind docker

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, development, full-node

Thanks to the bitcoin.stack community I have successfully launched a bitcoind docker with an external volume which has the block data

Currently its in 100% sync but I am facing an issue to get information using bitcoin-cli I need to run bitcoind -reindex and then add txindex=1 into bitcoin.conf

As I pulled the docker image from docker hub I do not have any control over its docker file and I have 140GB+ blockchain data that I do not wanna discard and start over

How do I run --reindex on a bitcoin docker container ?

Comment: I was mistaken It was a mistake thinking docker is kind of VM do not run docker bitcoin images if you are planing to extend and develop application, switched to LXC/LXD

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use volume you discard nothing. Next restart will reuse your volume.